# or condition not working as expected

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've the below XML statement

```
<section level="sect1">
    <title><content-style font-style="bold">PRACTICE DIRECTIONS</content-style></title>
</section>
```

when i try to apply the below condition

```
<xsl:when test="not(contains(./title/content-style/text(),'PRACTICE DIRECTIONS'))">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./section[1]/para/phrase">

        <xsl:value-of select="./section[1]/para[1]/phrase"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="./section">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="toc"/>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

It is working fine

Here I've another condition.

```
<xsl:when test="not(contains(./title/content-style,'ORDER')) or not(contains(./title/content-style/text(),'PRACTICE DIRECTIONS')) or not(contains(./section[1]/title,'ORDER')) or not(contains(./section[1]/title,'PRACTICE DIRECTIONS'))">
```

Here this should not let the condition(or the cursor) to get into the inner choose condition as there is `not(contains(./title/content-style/text(),'PRACTICE DIRECTIONS'))` as one of the conditions.

But here in my case the cursor is moved into the inner choose. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND instead of OR and you'll probably get the result you're after.

Comment: Thank you this worked, but a quick doubt, doesn't `and` mean union?

Comment: Think of it like this, with OR, if either condition is true, it goes in. With AND, both conditions must be true. In your example, the first condition is true, but you expected it to block on the second condition. This only works with AND, since it forces all of the conditions.

Comment: Hi @Tobberoth this is not working for `<section level="sect1">
<section level="sect2"><title><content-style font-style="bold">ORDER 39</content-style></title></section></section>`, can you please update the solution. Thanks

Comment: That's a separate problem. I would assume it's because your code is incorrect. Shouldn't `not(contains(./title/content-style,'ORDER'))` be `not(contains(./title/content-style/text(),'ORDER'))`?

Comment: sorry for that, here either of these are working. but how do i do in this section where i need to check the section/section text() containing 'ORDER' Thanks